# Is there a way to watch a question?

Tags: support, feature-request

I would like to watch a question for edits, new updates posted by the user, or new answers, comments added to the question. Is there a way to subscribe or watch a question?

Comment: Star to the side of the downvote.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/386878